# Riemann Zeta Function and Laurent Expansion

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-number-theory

In the wikipedia page "1+2+3+4+..."

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%2B_2_%2B_3_%2B_4_%2B_%E2%8B%AF

(and specifically in the section "Zeta Function Regularization")it is stated without 
reference that $\zeta(s)$ is given by the degree zero term of the Laurent series
expansion around $h=0$ of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n^{-s} e^{hn}$.
Is this statement true? I have some doubts becuase I found no reference to such
a relation in the literature about the Riemann zeta function.

Thank you very much for your help in advance.

Comment: The series $f_s(h) = \sum n^{-s} e^{hn}$ is divergent for $\operatorname{Re} h > 0$.  For there to be a Laurent expansion about $h = 0$, the function $f_s$ would need to have an analytic continuation to a punctured neighbourhood of $0$. It is not clear that it has one.

Comment: As I said, I think the statement is wrong, but since I know very little about complex analysis, I would like someone to confirm my thought.

Comment: It looks wrong to me, and what I wrote shows it's at least not easily proved, but I don't know enough about the case to say for sure. It is possible that the series has the required properties and the statement happens to be correct. I find it more likely that the wikipedia editor confused Laurent expansions and asymptotic expansions, however.

Comment: Would you mean the statement turns out to be true if we replace "Laurent series" with "asymptotic expansion"?

Comment: I would not be surprised if that is the case, but I don't know.